# How to navigate between HTML element using keyboard arrow keys

Tags: jquery, keyboard, navigation

I want my web page to allow navigation between blocks of text using the left and right arrow keys on a keyboard. I assume this would require Jquery.

I have literally read a dozen posts on Stackoverflow that seemingly address this question without really answering it...so please don't close this as a duplicate question

UPDATE: I simply want to scroll between articles (like blog posts) using the arrow keys. All I want is to scroll the page to the next divider.

Comment: Can you show up what your html looks like?

Comment: There's a mind-boggling amount of plugins available for this, one of my personal favorites is provided by the jQuery Tools library; [here's a standalone demo](http://jquerytools.org/demos/scrollable/index.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a JS Fiddle I made for you: http://jsfiddle.net/3NAwz/

This code shows div tags that contain text, floating to the left within a wrapper.  That is then contained in another wrapper that is smaller than the overall text (one section of it).

jQuery is then used to scroll along the content using the arrow keys.  The `.not(":animated")` part stops it from animating if it is already animating.  Using this just makes it nicer without a horrible long queue after some 5 year old decides to be very impatient.

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas aliquam erat vitae nibh convallis quis luctus turpis dignissim. Suspendisse imperdiet interdum consequat. Curabitur erat nisl, gravida et aliquet vitae, faucibus vitae lacus.</div>
        <div class="text">Donec dignissim lorem eu augue tincidunt facilisis. Etiam leo purus, tristique eu tempus gravida, auctor sit amet velit. Quisque mattis, libero ut pharetra luctus, tellus justo viverra elit, sodales scelerisque ipsum magna vel felis.</div>
        <div class="text">Pellentesque ligula mauris, volutpat id molestie posuere, fermentum eu lacus. Donec quis metus nisi, et accumsan massa. Morbi eget augue eget lorem semper cursus sit amet non tortor. Aliquam tempor rhoncus odio sit amet fermentum.</div>
    </div>
</div>​
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
    width:340px;
    overflow:hidden;
    border:1px #000 solid;
}
.inner {
    width:1020px;
}
.text {
    float:left;
    width:300px;
    padding:20px;
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-family:Arial;
}
```

​**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).keyup(function(event) {
        var key = event.which;
        if(key == 37) { // Left arrow key
            $(".wrapper").not(":animated").animate({ scrollLeft: "-=340px" }, 500);
        }
        if(key == 39) { //Right arrow key
            $(".wrapper").not(":animated").animate({ scrollLeft: "+=340px" }, 500);
        }
    });
});​
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I think there was a misunderstanding. I am not looking for a slider. I simply want to scroll between articles (like blog posts) using the arrow keys. But thank you for the quick response, I appreciate the effort.

Comment: Articles on the same page or on different pages? If they're on different pages, you would use an AJAX function to retrieve the content whereas if they were on the same page, you could either user `<a name="` anchors (maybe add some jQuery to smarten it up) or work out the height of the containing tag of that article and 'scroll' down that way.

Comment: articles on the same page...like a page of blog entries. I simply want to be able to scroll from one item to the next using the arrow keys.

Comment: What I said in my previous comment would do that perfectly.